# Where do I put .mdf and .ldf files to share an SQL script through git

Tags: sql, sql-server, git, repository

I am attempting to share a file that builds and populates an SQL database through git, but it won't create the DB on my team members' machines because the .mdf and .ldf files are located on my machine. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share a SQL script, you don't have to share the database with it!

What is generally done (best practice) is that you have the script needed to create the database (and eventually populate it with static/test data) in git, and then the user will launch that script to build the database.

**git is here to keep track of your source code and the changes made to it, you shouldn't put in it any generated file, and .mdf / .ldf files are typically part of what should not be in your git**. For generated files within your folder, there are ways to configure git to ignore them.

The value of git is to record differences between files, if you want to share your software, git is definitely not the good tool. Put those file on a shared folder (NAS), on dropbox, give them through an USB key or whatever.

However, if you really want to do this (**bad idea**), I guess you can add your files in your repository and either configure SQL Server to find them here or create a symbolic link.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great advice! Good to know. It was something to do with the auto-generated scripts from MS Server Manager.